# Error 403 dailyLimitExceededUnreg in Drive API Watch method Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

We are trying to observe the changes of a **Spreadsheet** using the **Drive API Watch method**. The idea is to rely on a **Channel** to get notifications when the file is modified. However, when we execute the method, the output is the following message referring to error 403.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

We are using the Oauth credential method.

The code that we are implementing is the following, using documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java):

```
final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    
String spreadsheetId = "xxx-xxx";

Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.setAddress("https://example.com/point");
channel.setType("web_hook");
channel.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
try{
    Drive.Files.Watch action = service.files().watch(spreadsheetId, channel);
    System.out.println(action.execute().toPrettyString());
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

We also implemented code to use a service account, but got the same 403 error.

Comment: Can you make other requests (like list the files)? Or all of them fail?

Comment: @Martí Yes, the request to enumerate files works. It is in the `.execute()` method where there is failure. Both the `channel` and the `watch` are created without problems.

Comment: All the functions do is build a request that is not executed until you call `.execute()`, that sends it to the server. So I'm not too sure what you mean by the problem `is in the .execute() method`. If there is any permissions error, it will be notified when you call it.

Comment: So, can you list the files? Or does it also fail on `execute()`?

Comment: @Martí We use the `execute()` method to list files and also to obtain a file and its information through `get()` (both works). In that order of ideas the permission error is for the `watch()` method, that shows 403 error as response

Comment: I'm guessing that you already [registered your domain](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#registering-your-domain), right?

Comment: Yes, the domain is registered

Comment: Hey, I was able to use a very similar code to setup push notifications. Have you tried going to [the Google Clod credential page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and make a new OAuth client? That requires to download and change the `credentials.json` and to regenerate the token